# Output SharePoint Document Library Files to CSV File Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I’m seeking how to output SharePoint Document Library Files to csv file.  I found script that get me almost there, but I can’t figure out how to update the code to export the information to a csv file instead to the console.log() or to an alert().  Everything I tried breaks the code.  I review other JavaScript concept that shows the how to add out to CSV but I again the script concept breaks the code I’m trying to modify.  The script I am using.  In addition, the script output the file names.  I like to get help on how I can not only output the file name, but I like to output, modified date, created date, and the link to the file.  I hope this is possible and I appreciate any help in achieving this concept.  Script I'm using follows below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function() {
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.DocumentManagement.js", createDocumentSet);
        });
    });
});
var docSetFiles;

function createDocumentSet() {
//Get the client context,web and library object.   
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("Fact Sheets & Agreements");
clientContext.load(oList);
//Get the root folder of the library   
oLibraryFolder = oList.get_rootFolder();
var documentSetFolder = "sites/nbib/ep/Fact%20Sheets/";
//Get the document set files using CAML query   
var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(documentSetFolder);
docSetFiles = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
//Load the client context and execute the batch   
clientContext.load(docSetFiles, 'Include(File)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
}

function QuerySuccess() {
//Loop through the document set files and get the display name   
var docSetFilesEnumerator = docSetFiles.getEnumerator();
while (docSetFilesEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oDoc = docSetFilesEnumerator.get_current().get_file();
    alert("Document Name : " + oDoc.get_name());
    console.log("Document Name : " + oDoc.get_name());
   }
}

function QueryFailure() {
console.log('Request failed - ' + args.get_message());


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample test script in chrome.

```
function QuerySuccess() {
            //Loop through the document set files and get the display name
            var csv = 'Document Name\n';
            var docSetFilesEnumerator = docSetFiles.getEnumerator();
            while (docSetFilesEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oDoc = docSetFilesEnumerator.get_current().get_file();
                //alert("Document Name : " + oDoc.get_name());
                //console.log("Document Name : " + oDoc.get_name());
                csv += oDoc.get_name();//+','   if more cloumns
                csv += "\n";
            }
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'DocumentList.csv';
            hiddenElement.click();
        }
```

Comment: This works great.  What I was hoping to accomplish.  What tweaks do I need to do to get it to work in IE as well.  Also do you have any ideas on how I can access the url to the documents and output them to the CSV?   I tried to accomplish that but no joy. Thank you so much!

Comment: Pending other columns to output  oDoc.get_name()+','+oDoc.get_serverRelativeUrl ();

Comment: That did the trick I got everything.  I was also able to structure the script you provided to download the CSV in IE (The default browser used at work).  Thank you so much for the assist.  Awesome!!!  I will up-vote this answer.

Comment: I have a quick question that I thought would be a no brainier but my brain can get it right.  To add a column with "Created" and "Modified" date will it be oDoc.get_created() and oDoc.get_modified()?  When I add this I get an error, Object doesn't support property or method "get_created() or get_modified().  Is this not correct to add this information to the CSV?

Comment: I figured the dates out after filtering through the data using the console.log.  To change the dates the names are as followed: oDoc.get_timeCreated() and oDoc.get_timeLastModified(). Now I have everything needed for my users.  I believe this issue is close.  Thanks for the past help.